# Visarjana Mantra or Stotram for Shivapuja

Tags: shiva, rituals, mantras, worship, shloka

I would very much appreciate the Sanskritam (Devanagari), transliterated, and English for a visarjana mantra or stotram for Shivapuja.

Answer (score 1):

रत्नैः कल्पितमासनं हिमजलैः स्नानं च दिव्याम्बरं नानारत्नविभूषितं मृगमदामोदाङ्कितं चन्दनम्।
जातीचम्पकबिल्वपत्ररचितं पुष्पं च धूपं तथा दीपं देव दयानिधे पशुपते हृत्कल्पितं गृह्यताम्॥१॥
Ratnaiḥ kalpitamāsanaṁ himajalaiḥ snānaṁ ca divyāmbaraṁ nānāratnavibhūṣitaṁ mṛgamadāmodāṅkitaṁ candanam|
Jātīcampakabilvapatraracitaṁ puṣpaṁ ca dhūpaṁ tathā dīpaṁ deva dayānidhe paśupate hṛtkalpitaṁ gṛhyatām||1||

Oh God (deva), Ocean (nidhe) of Mercy (dayā)!, (I have) mentally formed (kalpitam) a seat (āsanam) with jewels (ratnaiḥ), an ablution (snānam) with cold (hima) water (jalaiḥ), and (ca) divine (divya) garments (ambaram) adorned (vibhūṣitam) with various (nānā) gems (ratna); sandal (candanam) mixed --"aṅkita" literally means "marked, stamped, etc."-- (aṅkitam) with the fragrance (āmoda) of musk (mṛgamada); an (arrangement of) flower(s) (puṣpam) prepared (racitam) with jasmine (jātī), campaka (campaka) (and) leaves (patra) of bilva (bilva); and (ca) (fine) incense (dhūpam) as well as (tathā) a (brilliant) light (dīpam), oh Lord (pate) of the limited beings (paśu). (May all that I have) imagined (kalpitam) in (my) heart (hṛd) be accepted (by You) (gṛhyatām)!||1||

सौवर्णे नवरत्नखण्डरचिते पात्रे घृतं पायसं भक्ष्यं पञ्चविधं पयोदधियुतं रम्भाफलं पानकम्।
शाकानामयुतं जलं रुचिकरं कर्पूरखण्डोज्ज्वलं ताम्बूलं मनसा मया विरचितं भक्त्या प्रभो स्वीकुरु॥२॥
Sauvarṇe navaratnakhaṇḍaracite pātre ghṛtaṁ pāyasaṁ bhakṣyaṁ pañcavidhaṁ payodadhiyutaṁ rambhāphalaṁ pānakam|
Śākānāmayutaṁ jalaṁ rucikaraṁ karpūrakhaṇḍojjvalaṁ tāmbūlaṁ manasā mayā viracitaṁ bhaktyā prabho svīkuru||2||

I have mentally formed (manasā mayā viracitam), with devotion (bhaktyā), within a golden (sauvarṇe) bowl (pātre) made (racite) with fragments (khaṇḍa) of the nine (nava) jewels (ratna), clarified butter (ghṛtam) (and) an oblation of milk, rice and sugar (pāyasam) (along with) the five kinds (pañcavidham) of food (bhakṣyam) prepared (yutam) with milk (payas) and coagulated milk --not only "curds", as "dadhi" includes the whey too-- (dadhi); a beverage (pānakam) of banana(s) (rambhāphalam); a myriad (ayutam) of vegetables (śākānām), pleasant (rucikaram) water (jalam); a piece (khaṇḍa) of burning (ujjvalam) camphor (karpūra); (and) a leaf of Betel (tāmbūlam). Oh Lord (prabho), make (all this) your own (svīkuru)!||2||

छत्रं चामरयोर्युगं व्यजनकं चादर्शकं निर्मलं वीणाभेरिमृदङ्गकाहलकला गीतं च नृत्यं तथा।
साष्टाङ्गं प्रणतिः स्तुतिर्बहुविधा ह्येतत्समस्तं मया सङ्कल्पेन समर्पितं तव विभो पूजां गृहाण प्रभो॥३॥
Chatraṁ cāmarayoryugaṁ vyajanakaṁ cādarśakaṁ nirmalaṁ vīṇābherimṛdaṅgakāhalakalā gītaṁ ca nṛtyaṁ tathā|
Sāṣṭāṅgaṁ praṇatiḥ stutirbahuvidhā hyetatsamastaṁ mayā saṅkalpena samarpitaṁ tava vibho pūjāṁ gṛhāṇa prabho||3||

A parasol (chatram); a couple (yugam) of whisks --generally used as fans-- (vyajanakam) (made with) the tails of two Yaks (cāmarayoḥ); and (ca) a spotless (nirmalam) mirror (ādarśakam); the fine arts (kalāḥ) of "Gīta" --chanting-- (gītam) as well as (ca... tathā) "Nṛtya" --dancing-- (nṛtyam), (which are accompanied by) "vīṇā-s" --a kind of Indian lute-- (vīṇā), kettle-drums (bheri), "mṛdaṅga-s" --a portable drum with two heads-- (mṛdaṅga) (and) large drums (kāhala); a prostration (praṇatiḥ) performed with (sa) eight (aṣṭa) limbs or members --i.e. hands, breast, forehead, knees and feet must touch the ground in this type of reverential salutation-- (aṅgam); (and) hymns of praise (stutiḥ) of many sorts (bahuvidhā) indeed (hi). I mentally offer (mayā saṅkalpena samarpitam) all (samastam) this (etad) to You (tava), oh all-pervading and powerful (God) (vibho)! Accept (gṛhāṇa) (my) worship (pūjām), oh Lord (prabho)!||3||

आत्मा त्वं गिरिजा मतिः सहचराः प्राणाः शरीरं गृहं पूजा ते विषयोपभोगरचना निद्रा समाधिस्थितिः।
सञ्चारः पदयोः प्रदक्षिणविधिः स्तोत्राणि सर्वा गिरो यद्यत्कर्म करोमि तत्तदखिलं शम्भो तवाराधनम्॥४॥
Ātmā tvaṁ girijā matiḥ sahacarāḥ prāṇāḥ śarīraṁ gṛhaṁ pūjā te viṣayopabhogaracanā nidrā samādhisthitiḥ|
Sañcāraḥ padayoḥ pradakṣiṇavidhiḥ stotrāṇi sarvā giro yadyatkarma karomi tattadakhilaṁ śambho tavārādhanam||4||

You (tvam) (are) the Self (ātmā) and Girijā --an epithet of Pārvatī, Śiva's wife, meaning "mountain-born"-- (girijā) (is) the intelligence (matiḥ). The vital energies (prāṇāḥ) (are Your) companions (sahacarāḥ). The body (śarīram) (is Your) house (gṛham). Worship (pūjā) of You (te) is prepared (racanā) with the objects (viṣaya) (known as sensual) enjoyments (upabhoga). Sleep (nidrā) (is Your) state (sthitiḥ) of Samādhi --i.e. perfect concentration or absorption-- (samādhi). (My) wandering (sañcāraḥ) (is) the ceremony (vidhiḥ) of circumambulation from left to right (pradakṣiṇa) of (Your) feet (padayoḥ) --this act is generally done as a token of respect--. All (sarvāḥ) (my) words (giraḥ) (are) hymns of praise (of You) (stotrāṇi). Whatever (yad yad) action (karma) I do (karomi), all (akhilam) that (tad tad) is adoration (ārādhanam) of You (tava), oh Śambhu --an epithet of Śiva meaning "beneficent, benevolent"-- (śambho)||4||

करचरणकृतं वाक्कायजं कर्मजं वा श्रवणनयनजं वा मानसं वापराधम्।
विहितमविहितं वा सर्वमेतत्क्षमस्व जय जय करुणाब्धे श्रीमहादेव शम्भो॥५॥
Karacaraṇakṛtaṁ vākkāyajaṁ karmajaṁ vā śravaṇanayanajaṁ vā mānasaṁ vāparādham|
Vihitamavihitaṁ vā sarvametatkṣamasva jaya jaya karuṇābdhe śrīmahādeva śambho||5||

Forgive (kṣamasva) (any) offense (aparādham) committed (kṛtam) with hands (kara) and feet (caraṇa), or derived (jam) from speech (vāk) and body (kāya), or (vā) coming (jam) from actions (karma), or (vā) proceeding (jam) from ears (śravaṇa) (and) eyes (nayana), or (vā) from mind (mānasam). (Forgive) the actions that I have done (vihitam) or (vā) those which I have stopped from doing (avihitam). (Forgive) all (sarvam) this (etad). Victory (jaya), victory (jaya), oh Ocean (abdhe) of Compassion (karuṇā), oh Venerable (śrī) Great (mahā) God (deva), oh Śambhu --Benevolent, Beneficent-- (śambho)!||5||

इति श्रिमच्छङ्कराचार्यविरचिता शिवमानसपूजा समाप्ता॥
Iti śrīmacchaṅkarācāryaviracitā śivamānasapūjā samāptā||